# pyautogui.center, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subsriptable

Tags: typeerror, pyautogui

I'm trying to code a program to take care of some boring stuff. When I try to use `pyautogui.center()` I get an error. Here is an example of the code and the error:

```
c = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('sample.png')

d = pyautogui.center((c))



d = pyautogui.center((c))
```

> ```
> File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py",
> line 404, in center
>     return (coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2)) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of image is not found on screen too. But try this

```
sample_image = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('sample.png')
center_of_image = pyautogui.center(sample_image)
pyautogui.mouseDown(center[0], center[1])
pyautogui.mouseUp(center[0], center[1])
```

Comment: center is not having any value . Did you mean "center_of_image " instead of "center" while passing parameter in mouseDown and mouseUp?